# Why can't I solve this integration question by substituting root x with u?

Tags: calculus, integration

Integration of 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{x})^3}{\sqrt{x}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! It is not exactly clear what you are asking: did you try to solve the problem? If so please briefly explain what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this states
$$\int\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^3}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x$$
which **can** be solved by the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}\implies\mathrm{d}x=2u\,\mathrm{d}u$ giving
$$\int\frac{(1+u)^3}{u}(2u)\mathrm{d}u=\int2(1+u)^3\mathrm{d}u=\frac12(1+u)^4+C=\boxed{\frac12(1+\sqrt{x})^4+C}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did the same except that I opened the brackets for (1+u)^3. That's why I was confused. I do get what you've done though but would my answer be correct if I opened the brackets instead of using the general power rule right away.

Comment: @RR.Fouda : Rather than either choice you suggest, make the substitution $v = 1+u$, $\mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{du}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $$x^{1/2}=t$$ so $$x=t^2$$ and $$dx=2tdt$$
and your integral will be $$\int\frac{(1+t)^3}{t}\cdot 2tdt$$

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I think much more better just
$$\int\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^3}{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\int\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^3}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{x})^4+C.$$